# Having trouble with a combinatorial problem.

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is as follows:

10 teams divided into 2 groups 5 teams each are participating in a competition. The order of groups and teams doesn't matter. In how many ways can the teams be aranged.

My reasoning is that the 10 teams can be aranged in
$\binom{10}{5} = k_i$ ways now if I want to pair every $k_i$ team from those arrangements with other $k_i$ teams I would get one pair less for each subsequent $k_i$ arrangement and I'll get $\sum_{k=1}^{\binom{10}{5}}k$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: if you have 5 teams in a group, however you pair them, 1 remains alone

Comment: There are $\binom{9}{4}$ ways to choose the $4$ teams that will be in the same group as the Adders.

Comment: Your reasoning doesn't clarify the intention behind splitting the ten teams into two groups of five teams each.  It suggests you are trying to "arrange" a competition in which teams are matched in pairs, but that is not what you asked us about.  Ross's Answer explains how many ways the ten teams can be "partitioned" into two groups of five teams each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose the first group in ${10 \choose 5}=252$ ways.  Once you choose the first group, the second is determined.  You probably don't care which group is the first, so need to divide by $2$ for swapping the groups.

Once you have your groups, you can imagine lining one group up in any order, then each order of the second group makes one matching, so there are $5!$ matchings given the groups.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to the same answer as Ross Millikan:

For team #1, decide which other four teams will be in its group. This has ${9 \choose 4} = 126$ possibilities. This completely determines the split into two groups of $5$.

If you are also referring to the order of play within the competition, I'd have to ask for clarification on that part of the question.